# Swift operator declarations: What happens in a conflict?

Tags: swift, operators

This question is not about operator overloading, but rather about conflicts between operator declarations in different modules. In other words, imagine two modules declare the same operator, as follows:

```
// Module1

infix operator &+ {
  associativity left
  precedence 100
}

// Module2

infix operator &+ {
  associativity right
  precedence 50
}
```

If I use both `Module1` and `Module2` in my project, which of these declarations takes precedence and in what circumstances? Is it based purely on which one I import into a specific file? (That is my guess.) Is it global?

I am about to do an experiment to figure out this very question, but I thought it would be useful to have this question on SO anyway.

Comment: It would seem odd to export operators from a framework.  In other toolchains though, you would link with strong or weak symbols to resolve collisions - if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @chrisco I'm not sure I agree. There are well-known examples of Swift frameworks that export operators, such as https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift. Or think of a case like a parser combinator framework, which depends heavily on operators to be usable. (And in fact is exactly what I'm writing at the moment.)

Comment: It will then open up the Pandora's box that you are describing though.  As a best practice, it really seems right that if you want to get at the guts of something, you should statically link / compile the sources directly, and make all bundled (self contained) frameworks just that - self contained so as not to leak the innards and cause problems down the line.

Comment: Good advice in general, but I think the utility of custom operators overrides this. The idea of writing a parser combinator framework without exporting operators seems almost ludicrous to me. No one would use it. A better practice would instead be to (1) never override Apple's operator declarations and (2) recognize that operators are syntactic sugar and provide alternate means of achieving the same end in the event of a conflict (which is exactly what Apple does). I.e., make sure there is a public method for every exported operator.

Comment: Personally, I think Apple should take a page from Haskell and allow operators to be prefixed with the module name in the case of an ambiguity, e.g., `Module1.*` or something like that. That would solve a lot of problems.